# Java object instantiation reading a file

Tags: java

I am new to java. I have a class as following

```
import java.io.*;
class Lexer
{
     private static final int KEYWORDS = 11;
     private StreamTokenizer tokenizer;
     private String punctuation = ",:;.()";
     private Token[] punctuationTokens =
    {
    Token.COMMA, Token.COLON, Token.SEMICOLON, Token.PERIOD, Token.LEFT_PAREN, Token.RIGHT_PAREN
};

// Constructor that creates a lexical analyzer object given the source file

     public Lexer(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
    tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new FileReader(fileName));
    tokenizer.ordinaryChar('.');
    tokenizer.quoteChar('"');
    }
}
```

I wrote the following code to instantiate an object:

```
Lexer test = new Lexer("C:\\Users\\Kris\\Desktop\\test.txt");
```

It returns me this error: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException. Could anyone let me know how to instantiate this object give the class and the file "test.txt"? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

> `unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException.`

You also need to Surround your `Object` creation call with `try-catch` as it may throw `FileNotFoundException` or add the `throws` in the method from where you are doing this.

```
 Lexer test = new Lexer("C:\\Users\\Kris\\Desktop\\test.txt");
```

Moreover go for the suggestion of [Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch) for `FilePath`.

---

It may be possible your `IDE` not allowed to access files of `C:` drive due to `User Access Control` in `Windows` so better to run your `IDE` as an `Administrator` and Execute code again and please double check the path.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I did wrote double slash. I did not format my question very well when I posted. Sorry about that. Even I specify the correct path, it still returned an error. The IDE suggested use try and catch block. After adding it, it still not working.

Comment: I retried the try-catch block. Now it's working. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Great Glad TO Help You!! You should Accept One of the answers which you feel the one which solved the problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this

```
Lexer test = new Lexer("C:\Users\Kris\Desktop\test.txt");
```

Should be

```
Lexer test = new Lexer("C:/Users/Kris/Desktop/test.txt");
```

You could also use (the less readable, to me anyway)

```
Lexer test = new Lexer("C:\\Users\\Kris\\Desktop\\test.txt");
```

Because `"\"` starts an [escape sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html),

> A character preceded by a backslash (\) is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I did wrote double slash. I did not format my question very well when I posted. Sorry about that. Even I specify the correct path, it still returned an error. The IDE suggested use try and catch block. After adding it, it still not working.

Comment: Are you sure you have a file "C:\Users\Kris\Desktop\test.txt"?